# Can I install ubuntu on my computer by using a microSD card as installation media

Tags: system-installation, micro-sd

I am looking to install Ubuntu on my HP notebook, but I only have a microSD card and an adapter on me.

Does anyone know if I can install Ubuntu on my laptop with a microSD card as installation media.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can work. Many USB card adapters can be booted from, but not all. There are even built in SD card slots, that you can boot from, but it is rather unusual.

I have a few card adapters, and I often boot PCs from them (both SD and micro SD cards plus adapters). One adapter works with some PCs, another adapter works with other PCs. Some work with USB3, some only with USB2.

So please try. Good luck :-)